# How can I make a custom claim accessible inside a webapi secured by Identity Server 4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4

I have an asp.net core mvc web application and an asp.net core api project secured with IdentityServer4.
When the user logs in (to the mvc app), I add a claim ("mycompany") which I would like to be accessible in the api project.

I can access the additional claim in the mvc project no problem, but I cannot access the new claim in the api project.

How can I make the claim ("mycompany") show up in the api project?

MVC App Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                })
                .AddCookie("Cookies").AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = Configuration.GetSection("IdpConfig").GetValue<string>("IdpUri");
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                    options.ClientId = "MyProject.Web";
                    options.ClientSecret = "SomeSecret";
                    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                    options.SaveTokens = true;

                    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        OnTicketReceived = async (context) =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var claimsIdentity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

                                claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("mycompany", "some company"));

                                await Task.FromResult(0);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                // Log This
                            }
                        },
                        OnUserInformationReceived = (context) => Task.FromResult(0),
                        OnTokenValidated = (context) =>
                        {
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },
                        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) => Task.CompletedTask
                    };
                });
```

In the MVC app this works (returns "some company") but from within the api the claim does not exist

```
public static string GetCompany(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    var company = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "mycompany");
    return company?.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

they claim you add in the MVC application is added to the local identity, you need to get the new claim added to the access token that you send to the API. That claim you can add to the APIScope/APIResources in IdentitySever. You can't change the access in the MVC application because the signature of the token would no longer be correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After authenticating to the identity server, I use the userid to lookup data about the user in a different database (the mvc app database)... this new data is what I want to add as a custom claim (to be used by the api). The identity server does not have access to the mvc app database, so how would I add the claim to the apiscope/apiresource? It seems I only have the option to add the claim after I receive the access token in the MVC app?

Comment: Access token is self contained and it can't be changed without breaking its validity.Seems to me you have 2 options. 1. move user data and its claims on your Identity Server and add claims inside your token when creating it. 2. Create endpoint in your mvc app and make call form api to get data you want. I would personally go for option 1 because I think its better to have all user(and even company) related data on centralized Identity Server.

Comment: Better is to let the API lookup the necessary details as part of the authorization step in the API and let the access token just identify the user.

Comment: I like the "specialized authorization API approach". If not applicable, one more option is to expose an API in the MVC, call it from IdSrv and add all the widely necessary claims there.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it working

On Identity server you can add new Claim for user(AspNetUserClaims table) and give it a name company and value TEST COMPANY.
Add claim company inside IdentityClaims table and reference that record to IdentityResourceId of profile scope(IdentityResources table) so when your client app asks for profile scope IS will populate AccessToken with company claim and its value.

Configure MVC client to map custom claim and to be able to ask required scopes

```
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("MyCompany", "company");

//two trips to load claims into the cookie
//but the id token is smaller
options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

//configure scope
options.Scope.Clear();
options.Scope.Add("openid");
options.Scope.Add("profile");
```

If you get access token and examine it on [JWT.IO](https://jwt.io/) should contain custom claim company with its value.

```
var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
```

In your MVC client you can get company name like this:

```
var companyName = User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "MyCompany").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

To access custom claims in your API project, you need to include those claims in your JWT access token. In the case of IdentityServer4, you need to implement the [`IProfileService`](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/reference/profileservice.html) interface.

For example

```cs
public class UserProfileService : IProfileService
{
    public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        // Ensure adding claims to access token only
        if (context.Caller.Equals("ClaimsProviderAccessToken", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>();

            claims.Add(new Claim("<CUSTOM_CLAIM_TYPE>", "value", ClaimValueTypes.String));
            
            context.RequestedClaimTypes = new[] { "<CUSTOM_CLAIM_TYPE>" };

            context.AddRequestedClaims(claims);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        context.IsActive = true;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

You also can use [`IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#add-claims-to-identity-using-iuserclaimsprincipalfactory) to add custom claims to identity and then just filter them in the `GetProfileDataAsync()` method by `RequestedClaimTypes`.

Then in the `ConfigureServices()` method of `Startup` class, register the `UserProfileService` with `IIdentityServerBuilder`:

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer(...)
    .AddProfileService<UserProfileService>();
```

Now, your access token has custom claims which you can access in your API project, for example, via the `User` property of the controller.

*As it's already mentioned in the comments, it's recommended to keep the access token as light as possible and fetch custom claims only when you need them based on the user id in the access token.*